# error while deploying rails app to ec2 using rubber gem `response_call': Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request) (Excon::Errors::BadRequest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, rubber

when I do cap rubber:create_staging, I am getting the following error when rubber tries to create ec2 instance. Am I missing any configuration setting?

> ** Creating instance ami-eafa5883/t1.micro/elearn_production_default,elearn_production_web,elearn_production_web_tools,elearn_production_production,elearn_production_apache,elearn_production_app,elearn_production_passenger,elearn_production_collectd,elearn_production_common,elearn_production_monit,elearn_production_db,elearn_production_mysql,elearn_production_mysql_master,elearn_production_elasticsearch,elearn_production_examples,elearn_production_graphite_server,elearn_production_graphite_web,elearn_production_graylog_elasticsearch,elearn_production_graylog_mongodb,elearn_production_mongodb,elearn_production_graylog_server,elearn_production_graylog_web,elearn_production_haproxy/us-east-1b
>
> /Users/svisamsetty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:10:in `response_call': 
>       Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request) (Excon::Errors::BadRequest)
>       from /Users/svisamsetty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:355:in`response'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same problem.  It looks like it is covered as Issue #362 on the Rubber github page:
https://github.com/rubber/rubber/issues/362

Comment: Please summarize the relevant part of the link, the link might go away any time.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my excon version from 0.22.01 to 0.21.0

Adding this in the gem file and then bundle, fixed the problem.
gem 'excon', '~> 0.21.0'

I am not aware of the root cause though.

Comment: Downgrading didn't help, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating the fog gem by running:

```
bundle update fog
```

Aparently I was very outdated running fog 1.9.0. Now im running 1.23.0 and got to successfully deploy to EC2 by following Rubber's Railscasts (http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2)

This also updated the following gems to these versions:

- fog-core 1.23.0
- net-scp 1.2.1
- fog-json 1.0.0
- List item
- inflecto 0.0.2
- fog-brightbox 0.1.1
- fog-softlayer 0.3.11
- ipaddress 0.8.0
- mini_portile 0.6.0

Nokogiri depends on libxml2-2.9.0 library so be sure to have that installed

Hope it helps!!